# javascript function to check the correctness

Tags: javascript

i have an assessment here,and i provided a solution but when i run the code,the result is weird.
Here is the assessment:
"You are given a sequence of characters consisting of parentheses **( )** and brackets **[ ]**.

A String of this type is said to be correct:

- if it is an **empty** or **null** string
- if the string **A** is correct ,**(A)** and **[A]** are correct
- if the string **A** and **B** are correct the concatenation **AB** is also
  correct

input: The string contains at most 10000 characters.

Examples:**[( )]** is correct ,**(( )[ ])** is correct,**( [ ) ]** is not correct,**((** is not correct.

Implement the function ***check(s)*** to check the correctness of a string of this type.
***check*** returns **true** if the string is correct,**false** otherwise. "

so i did that code below:

```js
function check(s){
    if( (s===null)|| s.length===0 ) return true; 
    if (check(s)===true){
        check((s))===true && check([s])===true;
    }else{
        check(s)==false;
    }
    if(check(s1)===true && check(s2)===true){
        check(s1+s2)===true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }

}
console.log(check('([])'));
console.log(check('()[]'));
console.log(check('([)]'));
console.log(check('(('));
console.log(check('[(()])'));
```

But when i run that code i got an error message.

How can i fix my code?what is wrong with my implementation?nh

Comment: What do you think `if ( check(s)==true )` does?

Comment: if check(s)==true ,s is correct

Comment: So to determine what a call to `check(s)` should return, you call `check(s)`.  Do you see a problem there?

Comment: @Scott Hunter , what do you mean?

Comment: Your code is valid JS but doesn't make much sense logically. Can you add some detail on what you think each condition is doing?

Comment: a call to check(s) should return true

Comment: a call to check(s) should return true if s is correct and false otherwise

Comment: To quote you: "a call to check(s) should return true if s is correct" - how do you know "s is correct"?  You have not implemented any code to search for parenthesis `(` `)` or brackets `[` `]`.

Comment: Also, in general, please post your error message with your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply do a bracket match using stack (omitted edge cases for brevity)

```js
function check(s) {
  const stack = [];
  for (let c of s) {
    if (c === '[' || c === '(')
      stack.push(c);
    else if ((c === ']' && stack[stack.length - 1] === '[')
        || (c === ')' && stack[stack.length - 1] === '('))
      stack.pop();
  }
  return !stack.length;
}

console.log(check('([])'));
console.log(check('()[]'));
console.log(check('([)]'));
console.log(check('(('));
console.log(check('[(()])'));
```